# Python - Change the STRING type in invoke.task

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, task, invoke

I have a task that has 2 arguments:
x - floating point
N - integer

I want to have the arguments' type shown when I type --help in the command line.

the code:

```
from invoke import task, call
from capi_math import mac_exp
@task(aliases = ['e'],
optional = ['N'],
help = {'x':'power of the exponent','N':'number of iterations of the maclurian series'})
def exp(c, x, N=100):
    """
    calculate e**x using the Maclurian series up to the Nth iteration
    """
    print(mac_exp(float(x),int(N)))
```

current output:

```
C:***> inv --help exp
Usage: inv[oke] [--core-opts] exp [--options] [other tasks here ...]

Docstring:
  calculate e**x using the Maclurian series up to the Nth iteration

Options:
  -N [INT]    number of iterations of the maclurian series
  -x STRING   power of the exponent
```

wanted output:

```
C:***> inv --help exp
    Usage: inv[oke] [--core-opts] exp [--options] [other tasks here ...]
    
    Docstring:
      calculate e**x using the Maclurian series up to the Nth iteration
    
    Options:
      -N [INT]    number of iterations of the maclurian series
      -x FLOAT   power of the exponent
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way it knows N is int is because you give it a default I *think* this will do the same for x.

```
def exp(c, x=0.0, N=100):
```

A second option would be to use [optparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/optparse.html) as it gives you finer control over the output.  e.g you could then do

```
parser.add_option("-x", "--exponent",
                  metavar="FLOAT", help="power of the exponent compels you")
```

Comment: but now x is optional, and I want x to be mandatory, is there no way to do it?